# What is the best place for HtmlHelpers in an ASP.NET MVC Web Application project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I wrote an HtmlHelper and I'm wondering where I should put it in my solution.

Should I put it in a shared folder, App_Code, or a specific folder named 'Helpers'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create a ['Helpers' folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3formsandvalidation_topic3.aspx) in your MVC Web Application?

[image]